# C++ Libcurl can't clear headers

Tags: c++, http-headers, libcurl, request-headers

I have the following curl function which executes in a loop:

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    CurlResponse = "";
    host = "http://exaple.com";
    LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(LibcurlHeaders, "Expect:");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (host).c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, SSLPath.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, LibcurlHeaders);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, CurlVerbose);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, CurlPostData.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, LibcurlResponse);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &CurlResponse);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);        <----------
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        LibcurlError(curl_easy_strerror(res), host);
        }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
curl_global_cleanup();
```

Everything works fine when I remove the line:

```
curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);
```

However, in the [Libcurl Docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html) it shows to use it like I do. At least thats how I understand it...

So what am I doing wrong and/or missing?

Thanks for your answers

*** EDIT ***

So, basically:

```
LibcurlHeaders = null:

Curl call with headers
// cant clear headers
Curl call with 2 headers
// can't clear headers
Curl call with 3 headers
// can't clear headers
```

What I want is that the headers used in the curl call are cleared when the curl call is done so I get:
    LibcurlHeaders = null:

```
Curl call with headers
Headers cleared
Curl call with headers
Headers cleared
Curl call with headers
Headers cleared
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you have shown. What is the actual problem you are running into when calling `curl_slist_free_all()`?  It can only free the memory associated with the list, but it cannot set your `LibcurlHeaders` variable to NULL, if that is what you are expecting. Make sure `LibcurlHeaders` is initially NULL before calling `curl_slist_append()` so it allocates a new list, and then you use `curl_slist_free_all()` to free the list when done using it.

Comment: I set the     LibcurlHeaders to null at the start of the scripts. Well, my application crashes when I add the     curl_slist_free_all option enabled... I expect the function to clear the headers, because after a while I get a 400 bad request as response from the server because the sent headers are growing and become to big after a while... because I can't figure out how to reset the LibcurlHeaders (slist) of LibCurl

Comment: Well, don't you think that is relevant information that should have been included in your question? Always provide specific details, and a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action.

Comment: Also, since you tagged the question `C++`, you might consider using one of libcurl's [C++ Bindings](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/bindings.html) instead of using the C API directly.  Let the Binding handle memory management for you.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm quite new to StackOverflow and still have to get used to how it works :)

Comment: Is LibcurlHeaders always NULL before this code runs? Or does it still have the value from the previous time it ran?

Comment: "*after a while I get a 400 bad request as response from the server **because the sent headers are growing and become to big** after a while*" - that implies that `LibcurlHeaders` is **not** NULL before calling `curl_slist_append()`, so you are appending more and more headers to a single list that gets reused on each request. All the more reason to show a [mcve] to verify that.

Comment: It holds the value of previous curl calls, so it expands. The slist is set to null at the very beginning of the script. So, when a new curl call (which is basically called in a loop) executes again, the header list expands the previous list. Resulting in an 400 bad request overflowing header request after a while

Comment: What Remy said, and obviously you can't append to a list after freeing it. You need to start a new list for each request.

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren Why do you want it to hold the value from previous curl calls?

Comment: So, you are calling `curl_easy_perform()` in a loop?  Your example DOES NOT show that. Are you freeing and resetting `LibcurlHeaders` to NULL on **each iteration** of the loop? It sounds like NO, as that is the only way you could be experiencing the symptom you describe.

Comment: Remy, you are right and I though I made that clear in the question. All I know (which seems relevant to me) is that the slist is set to null at the beginning of the script and the header list is expanding with each following curl call since I can't accomplish to clear the headers list with the curl function

Comment: There is a lot of relevant information you left out in your question. Again, you should update your question to show a [mcve] (do you understand **COMPLETE**?) At a minimum, you code should have this in it: `LibcurlHeaders = NULL; curl = curl_easy_init(); ... LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(LibcurlHeaders, "Expect:"); ... curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders); LibcurlHeaders = NULL; ...` You have to reset `LibcurlHeaders` to NULL after calling `curl_slist_free_all()` and before calling `curl_slist_append()` again.

Comment: I have updated my question with the current situation and the situation I would like to achieve in pseudo code. Hope that clarify's the situation

Comment: Your pseudo-code (what is wrong with showing REAL code?) only strengthens the belief that you are NOT resetting `LibcurlHeaders` correctly between each use of curl.

Comment: I'm not at my house at the moment to copy the code. I don't know it by hard. Though, the code is complete besides the declaration of the slist named LibcurlHeaders... (which is set to null at the beginnning of the script, as stated earlier)

Comment: No, what you showed is NOT **complete**. You did not show what happens to your `LibcurlHeaders` variable in between each loop iteration. And you keep saying "set to null at the **beginnning of the script**", but C/C++ is not scripted, and if you are only setting the variable to NULL at the beginning of the program, or at least before entering the loop, then you are not setting it to NULL often enough. It needs to be reset to NULL on **EACH LOOP ITERATION**, and everything you have said so far does not sound like you are doing that.

Comment: Remy, you are right I am not. That's because the script mentioned is my script as it is. I will try your solution in a few minutes and come back at you with the results. It seems logical to reset it to null. My thinking logic was wrong, since I used LibcurlHeaders = with the append list function which is actually expanding LibcurlHeaders. At least, that's how I'm understanding the whole situation now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said in comments that you are calling curl in a loop.  Your example does not show that.  But assuming the code you did show is inside of larger code that is actually in a loop, you just need to make sure that your `LibcurlHeaders` variable is `NULL` before calling `curl_slist_append()` for the first time of each new HTTP request, eg:

```cpp
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    CurlResponse = "";
    host = "http://exaple.com";

    LibcurlHeaders = NULL; // <-- HERE
    LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(LibcurlHeaders, "Expect:");

    /* alternatively, and ultimately safer and more accurate:
    LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Expect:");
    */

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, host.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, SSLPath.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, LibcurlHeaders);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, CurlVerbose);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, CurlPostData.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, LibcurlResponse);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &CurlResponse);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);
    LibcurlHeaders = NULL; // <-- FOR GOOD MEASURE!

    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        LibcurlError(curl_easy_strerror(res), host);
        }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your example mad me able to fix the 400 Bad request problem. I used the line `LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Expect:");` I therefore didn't had to use the `curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);` or reset `LibcurlHeaders` to `NULL` neither at the start nor ending of LibCurl! Great solution and much appreciate. I would like to apologize to my poor documentation, but I really gave it my best shot with the code I had a the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren you still need to use `curl_slist_free_all()` or else you will leak memory. What is important is that you pass a NULL pointer to `curl_slist_append()` so it allocates a new list and not append to an existing list. You still have to free the list when you are done using it. You don't seem to have a good grasp of how pointers and memory allocations work in general

Comment: thanks for the note. Indeed, it's quite vague for me. I will adjust it in my code

Comment: I have added the `curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);` however, the script crashes immediately when added to the curl requests which use a header. I have used your code and it still crashes with the `LibcurlHeaders = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Expect:");` option. How is this possible... I'm really confused

Answer (score 0):

Wauw,

I managed to fix the issue. It seems to be a bug with Libcurl which can be fixed rather easily.

The problem was that I declared `struct curl_slist *LibcurlHeaders=NULL;` globally.

When I declared `struct curl_slist *LibcurlHeaders=NULL;` just before each `curl_easy_init();` call and removed the global declaration, the `curl_slist_free_all(LibcurlHeaders);` worked and didn't crash my program anymore!

***Short:***

The problem was the global declaration of `struct curl_slist *LibcurlHeaders=NULL;` which had to be declared in front of each `curl_easy_init();` function.

Comment: Why in my code? I am able to declare it globally right? Because I use many variables through my functions which works great.

Comment: Sure you can declare it globally but then you need to treat it as a global. That's outside of libcurl's scope. It just gets and uses the pointer you pass to it.

Comment: Oke, thanks for your clarification. I think I understand what you mean, thanks

Comment: Simply declaring a variable global instead of local would not cause the error. Something else was going on.